# How do I rebuild a Date from protobuf timestamp in C++

Tags: c++, date, timestamp, protocol-buffers

I am trying to extrapolate a string representing the current date from a protobuf Timestamp. I see in the documentation that there is supposed to be a class called DateTime but I don't see it anywhere.

Is my only solution to write the logic to convert from protobuf Timestamp back to "date" format?

Answer (score 2):

Once we know what protobuf Well-Known Type Timestamp is capable of (so that we don't reinvent the wheel):
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp

Then, proceed with C++ API Reference:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.time_util

Answer (score 1):

I just did something similar for `chrono::time_point`

.proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Settings {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
}
```

.cpp file:

```
#include <chrono>

Settings s;

if (s.has_timestamp()) {
    chrono::nanoseconds ns = chrono::nanoseconds(google::protobuf::util::TimeUtil::TimestampToNanoseconds(s.timestamp()));
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> timestamp(ns);
}
```